# underscore debounce in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js

What is the correct syntax for using underscore debounce in Coffeescript?
In my program, the following will print 'keyup', but will not print 'do something' 
My desired behavior is that 'do something' will be printed after 300ms after a user stops typing inside a text input.

```
    onKeyupEvent = (e) ->
      console.log 'keyup'
        _.debounce((=>
          console.log 'do something'
        ), 300)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.debounce()` returns a function. You have assign it to a variable once and then call that variable.

```
debounced = _.debounce((=>
  console.log 'do something'
), 300)
onKeyupEvent = (e) ->
  console.log 'keyup'
  debounced()
```